# How to create a 2 by 2 spread in indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Anyone know if its possible to make a 4 page spread in 2x2 format?

I am trying to make a 4 page design that needs to be printed on 8.5 x 11". Having 2 on one page would waste a lot of paper :(

Answer (score 1):

This site answered my question. Using master page and page tool I was able to solve my problem.

https://indesignsecrets.com/vertical-master-page-spreads.php

Unfortunately this does not create proper cropmarks

Comment: Just a tip: It's best to separate the design itself from the way you intend to print it. So you don't really need this kind of "custom" spread. Just create a document with ordinary spreads. When your design is completed, place the two spreads of the indd-file in another document and print from that.